# EF Core 3.1 Code First Table with many self referencing relation

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I didn't find an EF Core solution for this question, I only found about the older EF versions, not the CORE.

I have the following situation:

The company has a table Employee.

int EmployeeID 
string FirstName 
string LastName

Now, each employee can also be a Manager or Assistant or ...
But of course, a manager is also just an employee.
And an employee has one or more manager(s) and a manager can have one assistant, but an assistant can belong to more than one manager. Most employees will not have an assistant.

Question is now, in EF Core, what would be the best way to handle this?  Remember, an employee can have more than one manager, an assistant can belong to more than one manager. So is this possible to code first this in one table, or do you have to split this?

For example:
Employee table and we add:
virtual List Assistants
virtual List Manager

When I tested this, it didn't work obviously, you just don't find a lot of good info on this on the internet... I guess this is something that just not many go for and just try to split as much as possible? Like making an Employee table, Manager table where you link the ManagerId to match the EmployeeId and make a join table like EmployeeManager.
Just wondering if it was still possible in one table with certain annotations.

I wonder how one would make this if you would go for DB first...

Thank you for your insight into the world of EF Core!

Comment: This is a combination of inheritance and self reference and it looks like many-to-many between Employees, so you'd need an association class.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I actually tried it in DB first, so I could learn from the reverse engineer to plain POCO

This is the slq query:

CREATE TABLE Employees (
EmployeeId INT NOT NULL,
SurName NVARCHAR(100),
GivenName NVARCHAR(100),
EmailAddress VARCHAR(254),
ContractType CHAR(1),
LeaveTimeRemaining DECIMAL(4,2),
LeaveTimeTaken DECIMAL(4,2),
Primary KEY (EmployeeId)
);

CREATE TABLE ApproverEmployee (
ApproverId INT REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId),
EmployeeId INT REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId),
CONSTRAINT FK_ApproverEmployee PRIMARY KEY (ApproverId,EmployeeId)
);

CREATE TABLE ApproverAssistant (
AssistantId INT REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId),
ApproverId INT REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId),
CONSTRAINT FK_ApproverAssistant PRIMARY KEY (ApproverId,AssistantId)
);

CREATE TABLE EmployeeRecords (
EmployeeRecordId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
EmployeeId INT,
RecordMessage NVARCHAR(254),
RecordModifiedDate SMALLDATETIME,
RecordModifiedById INT,
FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId) REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId),
FOREIGN KEY (RecordModifiedById) REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId)
);

This way I saved tables, since the info for the Approver and the Assistant are in the Employee Table.